# lldb on macos does not use the dSYM

Tags: macos, clang, lldb

The result is, that trying to step *into* the d(11) call steps *over* it (returning the expected 22).

I have tried various tips I found. The most promising was `add-dsym` after the successful `dlopen`, but:

```
(lldb) add-dsym lib.dylib.dSYM
error: symbol file '/Users/myusername/Documents/dy-try/lib.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/lib.dylib' does not match any existing module
```

(Using clang 13.0.0, lldb-1300.0.42.3)

```
// lib.h
#define exporting __attribute__((visibility("default")))
exporting int doubles(int a);
typedef int doubles_f(int a);

// lib.c
#include "lib.h"
exporting int doubles(int a) {
    return a*2;
}

// exe.c
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include "lib.h"
int main(void) {
    void* Lib = dlopen("./lib.dylib", RTLD_LAZY);
    // does not help to change the path to absolute or lazy to now
    doubles_f* d = dlsym(Lib, "doubles");
    int res = d(11);
    return 0;
}

// Makefile
all: lib.dylib exe
lib.dylib: lib.c
    clang -o $@ $< -shared -g -Wall
exe: exe.c
    clang -o $@ $< -g -Wall
```

Answer (score 0):

When the linker builds your binary, it writes a UUID into the binary, which you can see with the command `dwarfdump --uuid <binary>`.  You can also see the UUID in the `image list` output in lldb.

Then when dsymutil makes a dSYM from your binary, it copies the UUID there.  Again, you can see that with `dwarfdump --uuid`.  add-dsym will only succeed if the UUID of the dSYM matches one of the binaries.  Otherwise, the debug session is likely to be very confusing.

So make sure those two UUID's match.  If they do and add-dsym still doesn't work please file an issue with Apple's bug tracker.  But if they don't match, then something along the way is rebuilding your binary after the dSYM is made such that the two UUID's aren't matching.

Comment: `dwarfdump --uuid` returns the same uuid for both `lib.dylib` and `lib.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/lib.dylib`. I have not called dsymutil, yet I have a dSYM, so does clang or the linker call it internally? The Makefile shows all that I do

Comment: On Darwin systems, the dwarf is kept in .o files, and a "debug map" is written to the executable with pointers to the .o files & link information.  Normally, you don't need a dSYM, lldb will read the debug map and link up the DWARF from there.  dSYM's are for long term storage.  But when you compile a single file w/o specifying an intermediary .o file, clang does what compilers do & makes a temp .o file & deletes it.  So it needs to make the dSYM right away or it won't be able to, so in that case it forces dSYM creation.

Comment: No idea why lldb doesn't like this particular dylib/dSYM combination...  But that is a fairly old lldb.